# Wrong Meta Title After New Domain

Tags: magento, sitemap, meta-tags, meta

Google shows my oldest domain meta title on their search results on one of my website after new domain.I've updated meta title every page on my magento admin store.Also new domain indexed by Google.

I generated sitemap file on magento admin page.

for example;
my updated meta title "Men's Cherry Concept" ( also new domain address:www.cherryconcept.com )

but google shows "Men's Kaan Silver" ( oldest domain address: kaansilver.com )

by the way,I uploaded robots.txt file to root directory.

I don't know where they get it from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google is referring to old content at your domain that is no longer relevant.
But you can prompt them to re-index via Google's Webmaster Tool. Check this article for more detailed analysis - http://support.aarcade.net/how-do-i-update-or-change-the-google-search-results-for-my-site/